# QuickBlox user auto sign-up

Tags: javascript, xcode, quickblox

I currently have an issue, that i need to register into chat system for like 250 users.

I have all credentials formated in .xls file, with name, email, login and password.

What kind of script i need to run, to automitically create all user?

or to create it from xcode app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any programming language

Here is just an example which generates 50 users with random login & pass

You can use it and parse data from .xls file

```
#define UsersToGenerate 50

[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    self.usersToGenerateLeft = UsersToGenerate;

    [self generateUser];

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"Response error: %@", response.error);
}];


- (void)generateUser{
    NSLog(@"usersToGenerateLeft=%d", self.usersToGenerateLeft);

    if(self.usersToGenerateLeft == 0){
        // print report
        NSLog(@"%@", self.report);
        return;
    }

    NSString *userFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"qbuser_%d", arc4random_uniform(1000000)];

    QBUUser *userToCreate = [QBUUser user];
    userToCreate.login = userFormat;
    userToCreate.password = userFormat;

    [QBRequest signUp:userToCreate successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {

        --self.usersToGenerateLeft;

        [self generateUser];

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"Response error: %@", response.error);
    }];
}
```